# Comparing string values in field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, string

I am trying to compare the values of 2 fields in my attribute table and update a 3rd field as a result. In the field calculator I have

```
CASE  when (("Address")  like  ("COUNTYNAME" )) then 'Match'
else 'Error'
End
```

so for the following toy data examples I would get the result Match,Error,Error
**Address,COUNTYNAME**

- Smith, Smith County
- Bob, Smith County
- Jane, Bob County

I have also tried `CASE  when (("Address")  IN  ("COUNTYNAME" )) then`

Are there any other ways to compare text values within QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to compare two fields together:

```
Case
When  "Address" in (left( "CountyNM", strpos("CountyNM", ' ')-1)) Then 'Match'
Else 'Error'
End
```

The `strpos()` function will return the index position of the first ' ' (space) character and the `left()` function "trims" the string before that position. The `-1` is to ensure that the space will not be included when doing comparison.

Here is the output of the above expression:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is :

`CASE WHEN "Address" LIKE ('%' || COUNTYNAME|| '%') THEN 'Match' ELSE 'Error' END`

for the LIKE fonction to work you need to concatenate (using '||' ) the '%' wildcard (replace 0 to n character) with your field name, also you could add some UPPER or LOWER to convert to all uppercase (or all lowercase) to avoid false negative

Comment: Is that not comparing the value from **Address** with a stationary COUNTYNAME instead of comparing the values in row [x] of field **Address** with field **COUNTYNAME**

Comment: This should compare the value of row(x) of the Address field with the value of row(x) of the COUNTYNAME field .

Comment: There is no ' around COUNTYNAME so it's taken as a field name, if you want you could put " around the field name it will work the same...